# How do I find what made my pc crash?

Tags: cpu, power-supply, gpu

While playing some games my pc will crash, either  my screen freezes or my screen goes off then my pc restarts automatically.

How do I find out why my computer crashed?
Is there a software that will tell me what happened before my pc crashed?

PC:
Windows 10 
Gigabyte motherboard

A10-7890k

Gtx 1050ti

300w psu

3 hdd

Comment: You should check system logs. That said, as a preliminary hypothesis, the PSU is likely insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many free software monitoring tools for built-in hardware.

Speedfan, for example, but ASUS has its own tools.

So then watch the temperatures and voltages.  Voltages are supposed to be + or - no more than 5% of the correct voltage.  The 12v rail can handle 11.4 to 12.6v anything else is bad.

You should also monitor temperatures to see how high they get.

Download this

https://geeks3d.com/furmark/

While its running see how high they temperatures get.
Also the voltages, if your 3.3v,5v, or 12v drop way down while the benchmark is running then the power supply is your issue.

It should plateau, and stay there.  Each time it plateaus, at a higher and higher level it should stay there longer and longer.  Eventually it should not go any higher no matter what.  If this doesn't happen your system is going to overheat.

Comment: 3.3v = 2.5v , 12v = 11.2 , 5v = 5.1v. Is this bad

Comment: Yes 3.3v *0.05 =.165 volts down max or 3.135v is the minimum.  11.4v is the minimum for the 12v rail so that is out of bounds also.  Your 5v is fine nothing to see here.  It can goes as high as 5.25v safely, but it should be as close to 5v as possible.  Clearly your PSU is too small watt wise.

Answer (score 0):

(I’m assuming you’re using Windows)
Check Event Viewer. Using the windows search bar, look up “Event Viewer” and run it. You’ll want to check under Windows Logs->System (navigation via the folders in the upper left) and look for errors and/or events about shutdowns. You’ll want to know the rough time a crash happened so you can check the events around that time.

Comment: I checked it and there error codes do you know what they mean (7009,7000,6008,41)

Comment: @John  - Google and/or Microsoft documentation.  Windows 8+ codes always have a cordensponding page.